# How to Disable Save Option in a PDF File and Browser when You viewing it on Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf

While opening a PDF document from a ASP.NET web page, the 'SAVE' option needs to be disabled (both from PDF menu and Key press) so that the user is prevented from saving the PDF document to his local machine.

I need to implement this task on .NET platform. Can anyone suggest me suitable Frameworks or Packages through which I can get it done this task.

Comment: You're fighting a losing battle - if the PDF is arriving on the users machine, there *will* be a way for them to store a permanent copy of it. Any additional complications you add may make it *incrementally* more difficult for them to do, but won't change things. Remember, at the end of the day, they might just point a camera at their screen.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: apart from Pdf. Is it possible to disable "Save option" in File Menu, when a user reaches a particular page in my website

Comment: The format is irrelevant to my preceding comment. The only way to do the sort of lockdown you're describing is to be the administrator of the machines in question and to also deploy additional software onto the machines (such as a specifically locked down browser/PDF reader). Since you've not indicated that you're in such a situation, the same analysis applies - if it gets to the user's machine, there will be a way for them to retain a copy of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not as simple as you think, because there is not one web browser. A web browser is a client, where you can not guarantee, that things like this works, so if you need this because of protecting data, you are on the wrong way.

This can not work.

**EDIT**

Even a lot of browser use different engines for rendering PDF and presenting it, for example some use there own, some use Acrobat Reader and so on. Some also directly download PDFs and not showing them (i think this was an option in firefox).

Comment: Agreed. Once the data is sent to the client, you have no way of controlling it. That simple.

Comment: Presently I just want to Implement it on IE. First I will disable Right Click, so that user can't save the file by "Right-clicking --> Save Link as ".

Can you please tell me is it possible to disable Save option in "File" menu of browser.

To disable Save option in pdf Reader, I think i should implement a customized pdf reader rather than using Acrobat Reader.

Comment: @SivaTarun even with IE this will not work too. You should consider finding another solution. Please explain the enviroment in which you want to use it.

Comment: the context is Protecting PDF files. We have several PDF files out of them some of them are confidential and intended to Read only for users

Comment: As Damien_The_Unbeliever said, if you do not have control over the client, it is not possible.